# How to sort result based on hit score in NEST elastic search with Highlights

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST(c#) to communicate with Elasticsearch, version 1.7.3

I am passing a string and trying to multi match fields in that string.
I am getting the Highlights to figure how many fields matched in the string.
Returing the results from the Hits.Select.

But the issue is, sometimes the most matched fields in the Highlights does not appear at the top of the list from Hits.Select.
Anything to set this right??

```
            var result = this.client.Search<PInfo>(s => s
                .Take(20)
                .TrackScores(true)
                .Query(q => q
                .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Type(TextQueryType.CrossFields)
                .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                .Add(f => f.A, 1.0)
                .Add(f => f.B, 1.0)
                .Add(f => f.C, 1.0)
                )
                .Operator(Operator.Or)
                .Query(text)
                ))
                .Highlight( h => h
                //.PreTags("<b>")
                //.PostTags("</b>")
                .OnFields(
                fk => fk.OnField( a => a.A),
                fk => fk.OnField( a => a.B),
                fk => fk.OnField( a => a.C)

                )
                )
                .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
                );

            string value = result.ConnectionStatus.ToString();



            return result
                .Hits
                .Select(c => new PInfo
                {
                    Id = c.Source.Id,
                    A = c.Source.A,
                    B = c.Source.B,
                    C = c.Source.C,
                    IndexedOn = c.Source.IndexedOn,
                    Highlights = c.Highlights // returning the highlights too from here
                })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the desired result.

```
            return result
                .Hits
                .Select(c => new PatientInfo
                {
                    Id = c.Source.Id,
                    Patient_Num = c.Source.Patient_Num,
                    First_Name = c.Source.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = c.Source.Last_Name,
                    Full_Name = c.Source.Full_Name,
                    Address = c.Source.Address,
                    City = c.Source.City,
                    State = c.Source.State,
                    Zip = c.Source.Zip,
                    Relation_Code = c.Source.Relation_Code,
                    DOB = c.Source.DOB,
                    Sex = c.Source.Sex,
                    IndexedOn = c.Source.IndexedOn,
                    Highlights = c.Highlights
                })
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Highlights.Count).ToList();
```